# No message body writer has been found for MultipartBody, multipart/form-data

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I'm calling REST url through CXF client to upload a xml file :

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("some base uri")
                                .header("Authorization",createAuthorizationHeader);
webClient.encoding("UTF-8");
webClient.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
ContentDisposition cd = new ContentDisposition("attachment;filename=abc.xml");
Attachment att = new Attachment("root", stream, cd);
Response response = webClient.post(new MultipartBody(att));
```

But I'm getting following exception while POST call

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: No message body writer has been found for class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.MultipartBody, ContentType: multipart/form-data

I tried adding providers :

```
List providers = new ArrayList();
providers.add(new org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider());
providers.add(new org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider());
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(constant.getUploadURI(),providers)
                               .header("Authorization",createAuthorizationHeader);
```

Still i'm getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

I tested your configuration it works  here is entire test file

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.ContentDisposition;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.MultipartBody;
import org.junit.Test;

public class KPUploadTest {

    @Test
    public void testUpload() {

        try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("d:\\uploadtest.txt");) {
            WebClient webClient = WebClient
                    .create("http://localhost:8080/api/kp/rest/upload");
            webClient.encoding("UTF-8");
            webClient.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            ContentDisposition cd = new ContentDisposition(
                    "attachment;filename=abc.xml");
            Attachment att = new Attachment("root", stream, cd);
            Response response = webClient.post(new MultipartBody(att));
            System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Please share where its failing, server side or client side? to further pinpoint the error. and also the cxf JAXRS version you are using

Comment: Thanks for reply . I'm getting exception on client side  while POST call 'org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No message body writer has been found for class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.MultipartBody, ContentType: multipart/form-data'   cxf JAXRS version 3.1.2 . Do i need to give any Provider for Multipart?

Comment: What is the stream you are sending, is it file? By default providers are enabled for multipart/formdata

Comment: I'm sending a xml file in InputStream.